# How to hide/remove a specific menu heading tittle

Tags: 7, routes

I have created a menu using [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) containing the following items: "Menu 1," "Menu 2," "Menu 3," and "Contact."

When I click on each menu, the heading title is displayed. I want to hide the contact menu title. i was trying to hide it from the block but each menu doesn't have a block title.

[image]

How can I hide only the "Contact" menu heading title?

Answer (score 8):

You should:

- select the Structure->Blocks menu;
- from the blocks list, click on "configure" next to your menu block;
- specify `<none>` as block title.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way: you can hide it by CSS, setting `display:none` to title.

Comment: i tried that, it hides all menus tittle but i wana hide a specific.

Answer (score -1):

It works

.is-active:before {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   content: "\f015";
}

This doesn't work
display:none